# How to properly use @InverseRelationShadowVariable in workbench

Tags: java, optaplanner

Using the `@InverseRelationShadowVariable` annotation causes `java.lang.StackOverflow` exception. My guess is that the relationship between the planning entity and the planning variable is now circular and causing unending reference during data binding.

Is there a specific way to avoid this while using the annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding `@JsonIgnore` annotation on the inverse variable.